# C++ How to cin and cout in same line?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to code a program for my project and I'm pretty much done. Now all I want to do is make the console look a little more designed for example:

```
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                 Please Login With Admin Credentials!"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                  ==================================="<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                  +   [=] Enter Username:           +"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                  +   [=] Enter Password:           +"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t                  ==================================="<<endl;
```

Now I want the user to input username and password in this specific piece of somewhat of a design. As you can see I want the username and password to be input before the +. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use system-specific terminal functions or a library such as NCurses.

Comment: Not using standard C++ functionality. There might be OS specific functions to control the terminal, or you could possibly use [VT100 control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm), or some terminal control library like ncurses.

Comment: If you want to start it only under windows, check the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/using-the-high-level-input-and-output-functions

Comment: under windows - include "windows.h", try to use HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, { 1, 1 }); // will move on coordinates 1, 1. The coordinates are in characters, (0,1) means the second character on the first line. You have to calculate where the + is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex I figured this is an easy & fast way to move cursor position!

Comment: BTW, you should not use tabs (\t) for spacing.  The tab has two meanings:  1) move to next {defined} tab-stop;  or 2) Substitute for a standard amount of spacing.  Tabs can represent 2, 3, 4, 8 or any amount of spacing.  Spacing depends upon the font; variable width fonts may have multiple spacing or its spacing may be smaller than other characters.  Prefer to use the "width" of the I/O manipulators.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ThomasMatthews I'll definitely keep it in mine the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use backspace to get back to previous lines, but you can use `cin` during execution.

If you consider the following:

```
std::string something, something2;

cout<<"                 Please Login With Admin Credentials!"<<endl;
cout<<"                  ==================================="<<endl;
cout<<"                  +   [=] Enter Username:           +";

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    std::cout << '\b'; // ---------- backspace 12 times
}
std::cin >> something;

cout<<"                  +   [=] Enter Password:           +";

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    std::cout << '\b'; // ---------- backspace 12 times
}
std::cin >> something2;

cout<<"                  ==================================="<<endl;
```

Will output something like:

```
Please Login With Admin Credentials!
 ===================================
 +   [=] Enter Username:hello      + // takes input 1
 +   [=] Enter Password:howareyou  + // takes input 2
 ===================================
```

From my aspect, this is the easiest way to achieve your requirement without any code complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Alex's advice of using `HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, { 1, 1 });` under Windows.h library & it works just fine! Just had to figure out the coordinates for my cursor.